# Wrong item "clicked" when using the "click" event on a SVG circle using D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm learning D3, and I came across an issue while creating a chart using D3 and SVG.
The full code (but with a subset of the real data) can be found here:
http://jsbin.com/lemazefa/1/edit.

**A simplified example can be found here**: http://jsfiddle.net/antoinejaussoin/G7zms/
(This is a better one, since it removes all the unecessary code around the problem).

```
.on('click', function(d, i){
console.log('I have clicked on '+d);
data.splice(i, 1);
console.log('Data is now: '+data);
update(data);
})
```

My problem is the following: when I click on one of the circle on the chart, I want it removed.

As far as I can see, on the first click, the right item is returned by the click event, then properly removed from the data array, but when I rebind the chart with the new data, the wrong circle is removed. And from that moment, the wrong data is associated with all the other circles.

Any idea why that could be? Is that a D3 bug? Or more likely, am I doing something wrong?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can't tell whats wrong with the indices, but you can use `d3.select(this).remove();` inside the anonymous `click` function to remove the clicked circle.

Comment: Your solution does work, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve: I wanted to react to a change of data, with rebinding, not just merely remove the clicked element (if only so I can try the transitions etc.)

Comment: The item to remove would be just `i` in this case.

Comment: Yes, and the computed index (with indexOf) gives the same result as i. So I do remove the item at index i (which is the correct item), but when rebinding the data, it doesn't remove that item (it removes another circle, and it seems that D3 put the wrong data with the wrong circle)

Comment: Added a simplified example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the attributes of the DOM elements that remain after the removals. This is because you are setting the attributes off of the enter selection, which is always empty after the initial append.

So, change the code to:

```
    function update(data) {
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data);

    // enter selection
    circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .on('click', function (d, i) {
            console.log('I have clicked on ' + d);
            data.splice(i, 1);
            console.log('Data is now: ' + data);
            update(data);
        })

    // update selection
    circle.attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("cy", 90)
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .attr("r", Math.sqrt);

    // exit selection
    circle.exit().remove();
}
```

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AhpTd/).

Comment: I think I finally grokked that pesky enter/update/exit mechanism, thanks :)